# Does a single EC2 Reserved Instances allow for multiple EC2 instances for a partial hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I understand that EC2 Reserved Instances are a billing feature.

I purchase **1** Reserved Instance for an `m5.2xlarge` in AZa and pay all up-front for the year.

Let's say I run **2** `m5.2xlarge` instances in AZa for the first 30 minutes fo the hour, then terminate both for the next 30 minutes.

Will I incur any on-demand costs for that hour, or will my single RI cover the EC2 costs for that hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: [Announcing Amazon EC2 per second billing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/announcing-amazon-ec2-per-second-billing/)

> With Reserved Instances usage you can launch, use, and terminate
>   **multiple instances within an hour and get the Reserved Instance
>   Benefit for all of the instances**. Bills will now show times in decimal
>   form instead of in minutes and seconds.

So you should not incur any on-demand charges.

Answer (score 0):

@maafk Yes, it will cost for that hour.
because you have reserved a single instance.
Also, there is an hourly billing.

Comment: yes, one ec2 server will treat as on-demand and it will cost you for an hour.

Comment: If RIs are a billing construct, and you're billed per second an EC2 instance runs, I imagine RIs essentially 'pre-purchase' seconds to run the instance type in the region/AZ. Two instances at 30 minutes during the hour uses the same amount of time, so how can I also be billed for on-demand?

Comment: This does not apply to instances that are running Microsoft Windows, or Linux distributions that are billed at a separate, hourly charge. I did some more digging, and want to issue a redaction of what I had previously said. You can in fact run multiple instances concurrently and not be billed on-demand pricing for one, so long as the image supports per-second billing, and the total amount of time used is < 1 hour. In your

Comment: example, if the instances were running Ubuntu, then they would likely qualify for not being billed under on-demand pricing, so long as the sum of per-second usage from the two instances did not exceed 1 hour of usage

Comment: Please note that, if you purchase an m5.2xlarge without an Availability Zone, you can apply the Reserved Instance discount to instances of the same family (e.g. you can run 2 m5.xlarge rather than 1 m5.2xlarge) [3]. Per our conversation